# Create silent installation using .iss

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, vbscript, silent

I have successfully created the .iss file inside the installer folder. But i have a problem calling it.

Command:

```
  $Process = [Diagnostics.Process]::Start("C:\temp\Setup.exe", "/S /SMS /f1c:\temp\abc.iss")
  $Process.WaitForExit()
```

There is no error in logfiles, but it does not run silently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [here](http://unattended.sourceforge.net/installers.php)

> The /r and /s switches only work if the release engineer is competent.
>   Many packages have "custom dialogs" which are not supported by
>   setup.iss, which means the dialogs will always appear no matter what
>   you do. For such packages, I suggest asking the vendor to fix their
>   installer.

Comment: You might try doing SETUP.EXE /? If you are lucky you may get some help.

Comment: @mc nd  - what options do I have to make the installation silent other than using record installation or convert this to msi. any reference or link I can use commandline using autoit?

Comment: If you have readed the information in the linked page, you have seen there are no much options. If you are not the creator of the installation, and can not request a updated setup from the creator... if the dialogs doesn't require user interaction, you can try to run the app hidden, or can try to decompile and customize setup package, or can track changes made by installation and replace with your own process, .... entertaining, but no simple things to do.